# Can a single Java variable accept an array of either primitives or objects?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, for a single method that reads the elements of an array, how can the programmer allow either an array of objects or an array of primitives to be passed as the parameter? `Object[] arrayName` will only accept an array of Objects, and generic variables do not accept primitives. Is there a way to accept either type of array without overloading the method?

Comment: you'll have to use a language besides Java, like Python, Perl, Haskell, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass an array of either type as an `Object`.

From there, you have to use reflection. In particular [`isArray()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray()), [`getComponentType()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType()), and [`isPrimitive()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive()) will tell the method what it has been passed. It's some of the unfortunate untidiness introduced by primitive data types.

Comment: For the same reason (so that it can also be used for primitive arrays), System.arraycopy takes Objects as its arguments (source and target array), rather than Object[].

Answer (score 6):

The only common supertype of `Object[]` and (for example) `int[]` is `Object`.  So the answer to your question is "No".

EDIT:  Yes you *could* use `Object` as the parameter type, but you'd need to jump through hoops (reflection or lots of typecasts) before you could use it.  And you'd have to deal with the case that the thing that was passed was not an array at all.

The OP's goal is to find a single type that is better than overloading.  IMO, using `Object` as a claytons array type clearly does not meet this goal.  It requires more complicated code, it less efficient and it is more vulnerable to unexpected runtime type errors.

Comment: he can use Object as a parameter type to achieve his goal.

Answer (score 2):

In java, all the primitive types have object wrappers. eg. `Integer` for `int`, `Boolean` for `boolean`, etc. If you are willing to accept an array of object wrappers, then having your method accept `Object[]` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the context?

Your situation might be calling for generics, with which you could pass in `Collection<Integer>` or `Collection<SomeOtherType>` as you please.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    run(new String[] {"Hello", "World"});

    Integer[] inputs = {1, 2, 3};

    run(inputs);

            //run(new int[] {1, 2, 3}); //this would not do!
}

private static void run(Object[] inputs)
{
    for(Object input : inputs)
        System.out.println(input);
}
```

}

It outputs : 
Hello
World
1
2
3

So, even with auto-boxing, the array of Objects cannot take primitves because array itself is derived from Object. Hence my answer to the question is NO.

However, in C# you can have the magic "var" to go around this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit different approach, have you considered a combination of [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) and [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)? This however requires a change in the higher level, so instead of passing an `int[] {1, 2, 3}`, you'll have to pass in `1, 2, 3`. Not sure if this matters.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    doStuff("one", "two", "three");
    doStuff(1, 2, 3);
    doStuff("one", 2, 3.3);
    doStuff(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"});
    doStuff(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
    doStuff(new Object[] {"one", 2, 3.3});
}

public static void doStuff(Object... args) {
    for (Object o : args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```