# Create an array of primitives or objects in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a single Java variable accept an array of either primitives or objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892599/can-a-single-java-variable-accept-an-array-of-either-primitives-or-objects)

I want to create an method that accepts either an arbitrary array. The array can be an array of primitives, or an array of objects.

Unfortunately, I can't do

```
public void myMethod(Object[] a) {...}
```

because primitives aren't objects! Is there a way to abstract this one level further?

**EDIT** I understand that I can pass it as an Object, but then how do I access it as an array within the method? I can't do:

```
public void myMethod(Object[] a) {
     Object something = a[0];
     }
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892599/can-a-single-java-variable-accept-an-array-of-either-primitives-or-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All array types are of type Object, nothing more sepecific.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public void myMethod(Object array) {
    Object first = Array.get(a, 0); // Object, primitives are wrapped.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public void myMethod(Object[] a) 
{ 
    Array.get(a, 0);     
 }
```

Comment: you still cannot pass an int[] to an Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no better solution (at the moment) than overloading `myMethod` to handle each kind of primitive type you want to handle. You can for example see the signatures of the `binarySearch` methods in the class [`Arrays`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Of course, you can also pass an `Object` and check if it is an array (and in this case, check the type of this array) using reflection. However, you're application will become less typesafe if you do so.